# 1970-01-01 stores in the DB when a user tries to input a text in the date field in laravel without showing en error

Tags: php, laravel, string, validation

In my laravel application, I have a form to register new users.

In that form, I have a field to input user birthday.

Even though I'm taking user input dates in `d/m/Y` format, from my controller I'm converting them into `Y-m-d` before saving them to the DB.

```
if(!empty($request->date_of_birth)){

                $date = str_replace('/', '-', $request->date_of_birth);
                $new_bday=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date) );
                $request->merge(['date_of_birth' => ''.$new_bday.'']);    

            }
```

I have the following validation rule for the birthday field.

```
'date_of_birth'=>['required','bail','date_format:Y-m-d',function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {

                $age=Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->diff(Carbon::now())->y;
                if($age<18||$age>70){
                    $date = str_replace('-', '/', $value);
                    $new_bday=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date) );
                    \request()->merge(['date_of_birth' => ''.$new_bday.'']);
                    $fail('Âge invalide. l\'âge devrait être 18-70');
                }

            },]
```

But now the issue is,

If a user tries to enter a text (like `test`) rather than picking a date from the date picker and trying to submit the form, it validates and saves `1970-01-01` in the DB.

**Use case- User types "Hello" in the birthday field and save the form. 1970-01-01 will be stored as the birthday**

How can I display a proper validation message and avoid saving `1970-01-01` when a user tries to insert invalid input...

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php See **Checking for failure** Think you'd want to set `$new_bday` to null or stop execution in those instances.

Comment: Laravel has a good validation. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you convert the user-provided value using `strtotime()` without checking it first. `strtotime('test')` will return `false`, which `date()` interprets as 0, which is 1970. And then in the custom validation function you are trying to do this conversion again before failing the request for some reason.

Assuming you're using a form request, your code should look something like this:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreUser extends FormRequest
{
    protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        // convert from user-input d/m/Y format if possible
        try {
            $birthday = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $this->date_of_birth);
            $this->replace(['date_of_birth' => $birthday->format('Y-m-d')]);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'date_of_birth' => [
                'required',
                'bail',
                'date_format:Y-m-d',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    $age = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->age;
                    if($age < 18 || $age > 70) {
                        $fail('Âge invalide. l\'âge devrait être 18-70');
                    }
                }
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely the better solution would be to not let them enter anything other than a date in the first place? At its simplest, using

```
<input type="date" required>
```

would force a date-format input on them, and disallow free input so that they cannot enter "test". Since that would result in a format that MySQL would accept (Y-m-d) then you don't have to do anything to the input in your controller.

Comment: Not to mention enforcing a single input format so that you don't need to guess what date a string like `01/02/03` represents, or simply assuming that the _guess_ the DateTime library makes is correct.

Comment: That's client-side only. You **always** need to do validation at the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing wrong date string, that's why getting `1970-01-01`

dump/debug the date before storing.

The following code might solved your issue

```
if($request->date_of_birth) {
    $date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->date_of_birth)->format('Y-m-d');

    $request->merge(['date_of_birth' => $date]);
}
```

Comment: `Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', 'adfadfasdf')` will fail the same way. This needs to be combined with validation code